# Convert request.json to DataFrame

Tags: json, dataframe, flask

Hi I'm trying to convert the string received from a POST method that results in a json string to my Flask API. I receive the Error: Expected object or value.
How can I convert the malformed json to correct form to fix this? Here is the code in my backend and I'm using jupyter to test

```
@app.expect(model)
    def post(self):
        try: 
            formData = request.json
            formData = {"0": formData}
            print(formData)
            df_json = pipelineTransform(formData, headers_df)
            df_predict = reorder(df_json, headers_df)
            #data = [val for val in formData.values()]
            predictVal = classifier.predict_proba(df_predict)
            print(predictVal)
            #types = { 0: "Iris Setosa", 1: "Iris Versicolour ", 2: "Iris Virginica"}
            response = jsonify({
                "statusCode": 200,
                "status": "Prediction made",
                "result": "Probability of Heart Disease: " + predictVal + "%"
                })
            response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            print(response)
            return response
```

In jupyter:

```
json_str2 = '''{'Age': '62', 'Sex': 'M', 'Chestpain': 'ASY', 'RestingBP': '140', 'Cholesterol': '175', 'FastingBS': '0', 
'RestingECG': 'Normal', 'MaxHR': '205', 'ExerciseAngina': 'N', 'Oldpeak': '0', 'ST_slope': 'Up'}'''

df = pd.read_json(json_str2, orient='columns')
```

the above string is what is printed from the print statement for formData

Answer (score 0):

Convert to valid JSON string by replacing single quotes with double quotes:

```py
json_str2 = json_str2.replace("'", "\"")
```

You don't have an index column in the data. So, you can use [orient="index"](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) and transpose it:

```py
df = pd.read_json(json_str2, orient="index").transpose()

[Out]:
  Age Sex Chestpain RestingBP Cholesterol FastingBS RestingECG MaxHR ExerciseAngina Oldpeak ST_slope
0  62   M       ASY       140         175         0     Normal   205              N       0       Up
```